# rate me, prompt engaged user, android alert does not show up

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

i am trying put this code

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * AppRater is a simple helper for Android developers, which helps getting
 * engaged users to vote the app. It requires a certain number of launches
 * and days installed before the rating dialog appears.
 * 
 * Adjust APP_TITLE and APP_PNAME to your needs. You should also tweak
 * DAYS_UNTIL_PROMPT and LAUNCHES_UNTIL_PROMPT.
 * 
 * To test it and to tweak the dialog appearence, you can call
 * `AppRater.showRateDialog(this, null)` from your Activity.
 * 
 * Normal use is to invoke `AppRater.app_launched(this)` each time your 
 * activity is invoked (eg. from within the onCreate method).
 * 
 * @author Chris Hager (chris@metachris.org)
 * @license MIT/BSD
 *
 */
public class AppRater {
    private final static String APP_TITLE = "YOUR-APP-NAME";
    private final static String APP_PNAME = "YOUR-PACKAGE-NAME";

    private final static int DAYS_UNTIL_PROMPT = 3;
    private final static int LAUNCHES_UNTIL_PROMPT = 7;

    public static void app_launched(Context mContext) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("apprater", 0);
        if (prefs.getBoolean("dontshowagain", false)) { return ; }

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

        // Increment launch counter
        long launch_count = prefs.getLong("launch_count", 0) + 1;
        editor.putLong("launch_count", launch_count);

        // Get date of first launch
        Long date_firstLaunch = prefs.getLong("date_firstlaunch", 0);
        if (date_firstLaunch == 0) {
            date_firstLaunch = System.currentTimeMillis();
            editor.putLong("date_firstlaunch", date_firstLaunch);
        }

        // Wait at least n days before opening
        if (launch_count >= LAUNCHES_UNTIL_PROMPT) {
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() >= date_firstLaunch + 
                    (DAYS_UNTIL_PROMPT * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) {
                showRateDialog(mContext, editor);
            }
        }

        editor.commit();
    }   

    public static void showRateDialog(final Context mContext, final SharedPreferences.Editor editor) {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);
        dialog.setTitle("Rate " + APP_TITLE);

        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(mContext);
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        TextView tv = new TextView(mContext);
        tv.setText("If you enjoy using " + APP_TITLE + ", please take a moment to rate it. Thanks for your support!");
        tv.setWidth(240);
        tv.setPadding(4, 0, 4, 10);
        ll.addView(tv);

        Button b1 = new Button(mContext);
        b1.setText("Rate " + APP_TITLE);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mContext.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + APP_PNAME)));
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });        
        ll.addView(b1);

        Button b2 = new Button(mContext);
        b2.setText("Remind me later");
        b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        ll.addView(b2);

        Button b3 = new Button(mContext);
        b3.setText("No, thanks");
        b3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (editor != null) {
                    editor.putBoolean("dontshowagain", true);
                    editor.commit();
                }
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        ll.addView(b3);

        dialog.setContentView(ll);        
        dialog.show();        
    }
}
```

which  i found here

https://github.com/metachris/android-apprater/blob/master/AppRater.java

according to the guide

found here
https://github.com/metachris/android-apprater/blob/master/README.md

i tried using

`AppRater.showRateDialog(this, null)`

in mainactivity of my app then the alert dialog for rating my app would be shown

however if i tried

`AppRater.app_launched(this)`

nothing happens even though i have changed

`private final static int DAYS_UNTIL_PROMPT = 1;
        private final static int LAUNCHES_UNTIL_PROMPT = 3;`

i tried starting app three times and even waited for one day still there is no alert , what exactly should i do so that alert is shown after one day **or** after 3 times app has been started

Comment: Can you try a complete uninstall of your app from the device before running & testing again?

Comment: did that but it doesnot work even then

Comment: Can you try with a value of `DAYS_UNTIL_PROMPT = 0` and see if that works? It will also bring down your waiting time and you can attach a debugger to see what happens.

Comment: how do i set to rate after 3 more attempts after remind me later is clicked

Comment: You can remove `final` from `LAUNCHES_UNTIL_PROMPT `, create a new method called `increaseLaunchCount(int count) { LAUNCHES_UNTIL_PROMPT += count; }` and call 'increaseLaunchCount(3)` in the `onClick()` method in the `onClickListener` of `Button b2`.

Comment: Button b2 = new Button(mContext);
        b2.setText("Remind me later");
        b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
             
             long launch_count =  0;
             
             if (editor != null) {
                   // editor.putBoolean("dontshowagain", true);
              //long launch_count =  0;
              editor.putLong("launch_count", 0);
                    editor.commit();
             }
                
                dialog.dismiss();
            } this worked